# Post php variable from one file to another

Tags: php

How can I post a php variable from one file to an other? I still asked this question before and got this answer back but it doesn't work. I guess it's because the two code bits are each in a different file. How can fix this problem?

**upload.php**

```
$filename = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
$ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);
```

**sound_upload.php**

```
GetSQLValueString($ext, "text")
```

Comment: You have to include sound_upload.php after the ext declaration in upload.php

Comment: You got three answers from people.  Why not comment on why they don't work instead of making a new question?

Comment: I think you have bad code organization, maybe you need require 'sound_upload.php' in upload.php maybe you need to refactor all implementation. but all I can tell that your question is very strange

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use SESSION...

use...

```
$_SESSION['ext'] = $ext;
```

in the first file and...

```
$ext = $_SESSION['ext'];
```

in second file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a standard HTML form (well, I'm sure there's other ways...) to post to another page, make sure you specify the page properly in the form data, then you can access the variables through $_POST on the new page.

As for files, I'm not entirely sure, but I suppose you could always try using

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

to see whether there's any sort of response on the new page through the posted form?